# Getting Position of a sprite in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am trying to get a each position of a sprite(curve),not only the center point,from starting point to end point.My sprite will rotate by 30deg when i tap on the screen.so i can't use `sprite.position.x-sprite.contentSize.width/`2 or some thing like that.Is there any way to get the position of a sprite or is there any other way to do this.

My need is i have different curve path.when i join those curve path,the new sprite should move along the curve path.

Comment: If you rotate the sprite, it normally rotates around its center position (unless you changed anchorPoint). So you can still use the sprite.position because it is not affected by rotating. Unless you meant to say something else?

Comment: Thanx for comment.My goal is i have different curved paths,Say 2.When i tap on a curved path it rotates by 30deg.so that when i join the curved path by tapping both.it forms a uniform path.i want a sprite to move in this path.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `convertToWorldSpace` function of CCNode.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you, you want to get sprite coord(not center, bottom left corner) rotated by 30 degrees? For x axis use formula: `newX = X + cos(30) * pathLong`. For y use the same but replace cos by sin and x by y of course :).